# How to use 'Construction Ship' in Stardrive 2: Sector Zero

Tags: stardrive

I have build 'Construction Ship' but I do not know where it can be used and for what. It need some special place in galaxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They build structures in space tiles without planets or asteroids. Move your constructor into one and u  will see a build option in the lower left of your screen.